# How to pass input to get statement in PL/I

Tags: command-line-arguments, pl-i

I am very new to PL/I.
I am using this compiler: http://iron-spring.com/.
I don't know how to pass the command-line arguments that the get statement is expecting to receive. It doesn't work for me to just type them in the command line (as I'm used to from other languages).
Also, the put statements are not displayed. As I have come to realize they are only displayed after the program is finished (in contrast to the display statement) and thus naturally don't show, beacause the program can't finish because it is not receiving it's required parameters.

How do I pass the command-line arguments? Or is there maybe another compiler for which it should work?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards